# How to use different database on development than production

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, configuration, phpunit

Becouse I developing on my notebook and on my destkop, too I want to use an sql server what I can connect anytime.

I want to connect to this when I'm on the development enviroment and use an other when I'm on production. How can I achieve this?

I tried this in the `config/database`:

```
if('env' == 'development'){ 
    $host = 'mysqlserver.alias.com'; 
    $database = 'mydb'; 
    $username = 'myuname'; 
    $password = 'mypwd'; 
} else { 
    $host = whatsintheenv; 
    $database = whatsintheenv; 
    $username = whatsintheenv; 
    $password = whatsintheenv;    
}
```

Comment: `if (App::environment('local')) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

This should be handled by your environment configuration via the `.env` file.

If you don't have a `.env` file yet, make a copy of `.env.example`. In there, you'll find these settings:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Simply modify these values to connect to the correct database server.

The `.env` file is excluded from source control, so your notebook and your desktop can have different contents in this file.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can check environment by:

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
  // The environment is local
}

if (App::environment(['local', 'staging'])) {
   // The environment is either local OR staging...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel makes use of the PHP dotenv library - https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv.

This means you'll want to create a `.env` file on each of your machines with the connection that you want to use. Then in your code, you can load these values using `App:environment('ENV_VALUE')`.