# Cannot connect to sqLite when testing Laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I get this error when trying to execute my tests (Laravel 5.3):

```
PHPUnit 5.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E{"sError":"An error occurred while connecting to the database ':memory:'. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'mick'@'%' to database ':memory:'"}
```

phpUnit.xml

```
<php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
```

database.php

```
 'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

What am I doing wrong? These settings work OK in another project?

I am not using config caching.

It looks like it is still using the values from my .env

Mick

EDIT: Just came back to this, I am using this to debug:

```
$string ="Name: " .  DB::connection()->getName() . " DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName() . " Driver: " . DB::connection()->getDriverName();
```

So, If I do this before the line that causes the error, I get:

`"Name: sqlite DB: :memory: Driver: sqlite"`

Then, this code executes:

```
 $this->actingAs($user)
            ->visit('/')
            ->click('Categories');
```

and again, I get the error:

`{"sError":"An error occurred while connecting to the database ':memory:'. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'mick'@'%' to database ':memory:'"}`

If I just do this:

```
 $this->actingAs($user)
            ->visit('/');
```

Then the test executes OK.

Comment: Let me ask you something, why you have the DB config out of .env?

Comment: Are you trying to say, why have I taken my settings out of the .env file? I haven't, when testing, the values from phpunit.xml are used.

Comment: What OS do you use? Can you run following command `$ sqlite3`?

Comment: Linux - Centos. Yes.

Comment: X-Ref: [How to use different database on development than production](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45479858/367456)

Comment: phpunit.xml is used for testing

Answer (score 0):

The error message you report in your question:

> An error occurred while connecting to the database ':memory:'. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'mick'@'%' to database ':memory:'

This shows that not a Sqlite database is used but a Mysql one. I'm not fluent with Laravel at all, but I'd say there is some fall-back to Mysql in action. For testing purposes I would remove the Mysql from the overall configuration and see what that turns up.

That's quite different to what you decided to do, that is to switch to Mysql entirely (according to your post on the Laracast forums).

Comment: I deleted all the mysql details and now I get this: 
```{"sError":"An error occurred while connecting to the database ':memory:'. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database ':memory:'"}[mick@devwebapplication-02 dashboards]$ ```

Comment: @Mick: This is still a Mysql driver errror message. Could it be that Laravel is auto-wired to Mysql by default? I think you need to break out of that. Additionally it shows that Laravel is not at all even remotely thinking about making use of your testing database configuration. Which means this is still at the level of a configuration issue. The Laravel documentation should provide more details here (as written not fluent w/ Laravel, no idea if the documentation is covering these basic things of application configuration, but I'd say it should).

Comment: Thanks @hakre , my thoughts exactly. The weird thing is that I have this working in a different project and cannot see any difference between the two.

Comment: @Mick: I can imagine that this can be weird, but I'm out of hints for that. As written, not fluent with Laravel. Somewhat a pity the docs aren't clear about this, the scenario seems rather straight forward, no idea which esoteric magic might be in place there. Perhaps just a configuration issue.